# JS How to Best Group By and Do Value Lookup/Replacement

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by

I'm writing a program that returns a bunch of tasks with timestamps assigned to users and I'm wondering how best to transform the two datasets involved for display.

My tasks data structure looks something like this:

```
tasks = [{
    "id": 1,
    "resource_id": 1,
    "day": '2019-10-29'
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "resource_id": 1,
    "day": '2019-10-28'
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "resource_id": 1,
    "day": '2019-10-30'
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "resource_id": 2,
    "day": '2019-10-31'
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "resource_id": 2,
    "day": '2019-10-30'
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "resource_id": 2,
    "day": '2019-10-28'
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "resource_id": 3,
    "day": '2019-10-28'
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "resource_id": 3,
    "day": '2019-10-29'
}]
```

And users like so:

```
users = [{ 
   "id": 1,
   "first_name": "Anthony",
   "last_name": "Smith",
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Jason",
    "last_name": "Jones",
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "first_name": "Billy",
    "last_name": "Phllips",
}]
```

1. `task.resource_id` links to `user.id`.
2. `task.day` will always be a working day.
3. A user may have multiple tasks in the week but only 1 per day.

So I guess what I'm really trying to achieve now is how to transform my 2 data sets to best display all tasks for a user, where the tasks for said user is ordered by date.

In the above data example the output would look like:

```
Anthony Smith: Mon 28th, Tue 29th, Wed 30th
Jason Jones: Mon 28th, Wed 30th, Thur 31st
Billy Phillips: Mon 28th, Tue 29th
```

I don't care that the user names be ordered by the earlier task of that user, so long as the dates of tasks within that user is ordered.

What I've come up with so far to transform my tasks:

```
let grouped_tasks = tasks.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.resource_id] = r[a.resource_id] || [];
    r[a.resource_id].push(a);
    return r;
}, Object.create(null));
```

Which essentially groups the tasks by `task.resource.id`, appending that `task.resource_id` as a key for that grouping. This should then make it much easier to do a lookup in `users.id` for `task.resource_id` in order then get the first and last name of the user.

From there I'd also have to sort by `day` ascending, however I can't help but feel there is a cleaner, better solution to this problem than what I have achieved so far.

I'd really appreciate the help! :)

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a code review.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes that sounds like a code review.  Your code is fine, given your data set.  Grouping the list by user is something you must do if you want to do it efficiently, and your attempt is better than many that I've seen.

Comment: What I'm unsure of is how to do the looping/replacement of the `resource_id` with the name, as well as the ordering of the task date within the loop for the user.